# retrieve perimeter points relative to center point in grid

Tags: grid, point

Given `p(0,0)`, how do I retrieve `points{(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(1,-1),(0,-1),(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1)}` which are the perimeter points relative to p offset by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(x = p.x -1; x <= p.x + 1; x++) {
    for(y = p.y -1; y <= p.y + 1; y++) {
        // Do some stuff with each p
    }
}
```

Generic code here. Alter for your programming language and how you store the points.

Comment: I am looking for a way to have a list of all perimeter points in Python: `[(x,y), ...]`. Any idea if there is a way to do that in a single line?